# Formula/algorithm to offset GPS coordinations

Tags: gps, geolocation, coordinates, offset, trigonometry

I have GPS coordinates provided as degrees latitude, longitude and would like to offset them by a distance and an angle.

E.g.: What are the new coordinates if I offset `45.12345`, `7.34567` by 22km along bearing 104 degrees ?

Thanks

Comment: This is actually a complicated problem.  Are you taking into account terrain?  Are you assuming the Earth is a sphere?

Comment: The distance I am looking at is around 20 km, rarely more. But would like to have a result which is +-1km from the truth.

Comment: Are you taking into account terrain? Are you assuming the Earth is a sphere?  What is "truth"?  There are a lot of ways to measure the distance between point A and B, and it gets complex at short distances.

Comment: Yes, I do assume it's a sphere, not a plane.

Comment: To clarify, are you assuming the Earth is a **perfect** sphere?  The Earth isn't, but a lot of folks use a sphere to approximate since it's much easier.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Please describe the application of that desired formula: vehicles, airplanes, ships? And whether you can ignore extreme cases like in polar regions or at poles. And for what you need that. Usually one can ignore polar regions, and ignore terrain (mountains). What is the maximum offset distance to be needed? some 10 to 100km or some thouand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most applications one of these two formulas are sufficient:

["Lat/lon given radial and distance"](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#LL)

The second one is slower, but makes less problems in special situations (see docu on that page).
Read the introduction on that page, and make sure that lat/lon are converted to radians before and back to degrees after having the result.
Make sure that your system uses atan2(y,x) (which is usually the case) and not atan2(x,y) which is the case in Excell.

Comment: The link is not working anymore. Can you please update the link?

Answer (score 1):

The link in the previous answer no longer works, here is the link using the way back machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20161209044600/http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm

The formula is:

A point {lat,lon} is a distance d out on the tc radial from point 1 if:

```
 lat=asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d)+cos(lat1)*sin(d)*cos(tc))
 IF (cos(lat)=0)
    lon=lon1      // endpoint a pole
 ELSE
    lon=mod(lon1-asin(sin(tc)*sin(d)/cos(lat))+pi,2*pi)-pi
 ENDIF
```

This algorithm is limited to distances such that dlon <pi/2, i.e those that extend around less than one quarter of the circumference of the earth in longitude. A completely general, but more complicated algorithm is necessary if greater distances are allowed:

```
 lat =asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d)+cos(lat1)*sin(d)*cos(tc))
 dlon=atan2(sin(tc)*sin(d)*cos(lat1),cos(d)-sin(lat1)*sin(lat))
 lon=mod( lon1-dlon +pi,2*pi )-pi
```