# create geopoint in radius of another point (latitude/longitude) maybe with geotools

Tags: java, latitude-longitude, geotools

I'm really new at [geotools](http://geotools.org/) (and I'm not sure if it's the best solution for my problem). I've got a list of latitude/longitude and want to create for each point another point (latitude/longitude) in radius of x meters. I don't need a map or something like that, because I only want to store the generated latitude/longitudes in database for future use.  It would be nice to say, where the items are (e.g. they shouldn't be in a sea). The application will run automatically from server (each day or once in week).

Comment: there are infinity number of points with radius r from an location. You probably want a direction measured in degrees, too.

Comment: yeah, that doesn't matter for me, I need a random point in radius of the given point. But I don't know how to create a point even when degree is given... . Can you give me an example?

Comment: See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807471/formula-algorithm-to-offset-gps-coordinations/27825118#27825118

Comment: However "They shouldn't be in sea" is incredible more work.

Comment: thank you! Yeah, "not in sea" would be nice but is optional :) The answer you suggested is a native solution, but I'd like to use the library instead. Maybe I'm able to generate a random degree, calculate the point for radius x with generated degree and get lat/long of this point? I'm just really new in this topic and don't know how the code should look like... .

Comment: With that link to th eother answer, which you can upvote, gives the correct formula. You just have to convert from degrees to radians. This is the easiest solution, and Geotools may not have such a function. You can test your code with a standard methods that calculates the distance between that two points, which should then be the radius used before. Calcukaring a random value from 0 - 360  is not be difficult.